# Custom JQuery event firing in one place but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, custom-events

This is probably just my own ignorance of how events work, but can someone explain this: A custom event will not fire at the top of a function, but will fire in a callback inside that function.

The following works (the custom event fires):

```
function foo() {

    $.ajax( ... , function() {
            $.event.trigger("custom" , data );
    });

}

foo();
```

The following does not work (the custom event does not fire):

```
function foo() {
    $.event.trigger("custom" , data );

    $.ajax( ... , function() {
            ...
    });

}

foo();
```

The event binding is as follows:

```
$(document).bind("custom custom1 custom2" , function( event, data ) {
    ...
});
```

I really want it to fire right at the top of the function. Any help is most appreciated!

NOTE: It's the same issue across browsers, and with or without the extra data argument.

Comment: The end got clipped: ...same issue across browsers, and with or without the extra data argument.

Comment: Is it possible you bind the handler *after* calling `foo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it works in the async callback leads me to believe that when foo(); is called, the actual binding hasn't taken place.  You need to be careful about the order of things when you do this.

jwwishart's answer probably works because he's binding first... then calling foo.  If you post the whole code with the order of where things happen though it might be easier to debug.

Comment: Yes. So simple. I thought the binding was in init but it was elsewhere, inside an asynch callback. I was thrown off by the fact that it consistently worked/broke when I moved it in and out of the callback in the same function. Silly me! Thanks to you and sje397 and everyone else who took the time.

Answer (score 1):

`data` appears to be undefined in your second (non-working) method.

When I define `data`, it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more faithful to the original code. Data is always defined in advance of the trigger. But I have the same problem when I remove the data parameter all together.

Comment: Good point. I saw that but had my mind focused on getting a simple working piece of code such that I didn't think it could have been his problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following works... ?

I only bound the "custom" even, I removed the other two (to get things as simple as possible.)

```
$(document).bind("custom" , function( event, data ) {
    alert(data);
});


function foo() {
    $.event.trigger("custom" , "Works" );
}

foo();
```